# Access Denied while querying S3 files from AWS Athena within Lambda in different account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-athena

I am trying to query Athena View from my Lambda code. Created Athena table for S3 files which are in different account. Athena Query editor is giving me below error:

> Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied;

I tried accessing Athena View from my Lambda code. Created Lambda Execution Role and allowed this role in Bucket Policy of another account S3 bucket as well like below:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::2222222222:role/BAccountRoleFullAccess"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/A-Role",
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/B-Role"
                ]
            },
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::s3_bucket/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

From Lambda, getting below error:

```
    'Status': {'State': 'FAILED', 'StateChangeReason': 'com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
        Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 3A8953784EC73B17; 
    S3 Extended Request ID: LfQZdTCj7sSQWcBqVNhtHrDEnJuGxgJQxvillSHznkWIr8t5TVzSaUwNSdSNh+YzDUj+S6aOUyI=), 
    S3 Extended Request ID: LfQZdTCj7sSQWcBqVNhtHrDEnJuGxgJQxvillSHznkWIr8t5TVzSaUwNSdSNh+YzDUj+S6aOUyI=
 (Path: s3://s3_bucket/Input/myTestFile.csv)'
```

This Lambda function is using `arn:aws:iam::111111111:role/B-Role` Execution role which has full access to Athena and S3.

Someone please guide me.

Comment: So the bucket is in account `2222222222`, and the lambda in `111111111`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reproduce this situation, I did the following:

- In `Account-A`, created an **Amazon S3 bucket** (`Bucket-A`) and uploaded a CSV file
- In `Account-B`, created an **IAM Role** (`Role-B`) with S3 and Athena permissions
- Turned *OFF* **Block Public Access** on `Bucket-A`
- Added a **bucket policy** to `Bucket-A` that references `Role-B`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::[ACCOUNT-B]:role/role-b"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-a/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

- In `Account-B`, manually defined a **table** in the Amazon Athena console
- Ran a query on the Athena table. As expected, received `Access Denied` because I was using an IAM User to access the console, not the IAM Role defined in the Bucket Policy on `Bucket-A`
- Created an **AWS Lambda function** in `Account-B` that uses `Role-B`:

```py
import boto3
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    athena_client = boto3.client('athena')
    query1 = athena_client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString='SELECT * FROM foo',
        ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': 's3://my-athena-out-bucket/'}
    )
    time.sleep(10)

    query2 = athena_client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId=query1['QueryExecutionId'])
    print(query2)
```

- Ran the Lambda function. It **successfully returned data from the CSV file**.

Please compare your configurations against the above steps that I took. Hopefully you will find a difference that will enable your cross-account access by Athena.

Reference: [Cross-account Access - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cross-account-permissions.html)

Comment: thank you John! It worked. I did the same configuration but don't know why it was not working. I tried again and it worked.

Comment: Can we have Athena also in account A same where S3 buckets are created. Can Lambda call Athena View from different account.

Comment: **Can we have Athena also in account A same where S3 buckets are created?** Yes, there is nothing special required here. Just use Athena. **Can Lambda call Athena View from different account?** The above shows how to use Lambda to access Athena in a different account. It doesn't impact what you do _within_ Athena. You can use a table, or a view, or whatever you want in Athena.

Comment: It gives me error that the Schema does not exist. I created the Database in Account A, created View under that schema and tried calling the view from Lambda in account B. Got error saying 'Schema does not exist'. Is it because it is searching the schema in Account B only where Lambda is present.

Comment: Wait a second, this is getting confusing as to which account has which service. Please create a new Question since this is now getting different to the content of this Question.

Comment: Ceated new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60506048/access-aws-athena-from-python-lambda-in-different-account/60506919?noredirect=1#comment107050728_60506919         PLease guide