# Access AWS Athena from Python Lambda in different account

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-athena

I have two account A and B. S3 Buckets and Athena View is in account A and Lambda is in Account B. I want to call Athena from my Lambda. I have also allowed Lambda Execution Role in S3 Bucket Policy. When I try to call Database from Lambda, it gives me error as `'Status': {'State': 'FAILED', 'StateChangeReason': 'SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:15: Schema db_name does not exist'`

Below is my Lambda Code:

```
import boto3
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    athena_client = boto3.client('athena')
    client_exc = athena_client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString='SELECT * FROM db_name.athena_view',
        ResultConfiguration={'OutputLocation': 's3://my-athena-out-bucket/'}
    )

    resp= athena_client.get_query_results(QueryExecutionId=client_exc['QueryExecutionId'])
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Do following-

Account(A) Create a IAM-Role which have access to Athena and S3 bucket and Also add permissions for the Role in account B to call Assume Role on this role.

Account(B)  Create a IAM Role and assigned it to Lambda that will assume role of Account A which have access to Athena and S3 on Temporary basis.

See following link -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_create_for-user.html

Comment: I am not getting access denied error. I have added IAM role created in Account B in Bucket Policy of Account A S3 bucket.

Comment: QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database':'database name 
        }
Add above parameters to start_query_execution function.

Comment: Added this as well but no luck.. # Execution
    response = client.start_query_execution(
        QueryString='SELECT * FROM db_name.athena_view',
        QueryExecutionContext={
            'Database': 'db_name'
        },
        ResultConfiguration={
            'OutputLocation': 's3://my-athena-out-bucket/'
        }
    )

Comment: Did you checked lambda is connecting to athena of Account A where table exists and not in account B??

Comment: That's the issue. I am able to connect to Athena if it exixts in Account B where Lambda is. But when I move Athena to Account A where table exixts then I am getting Schema not found error.

Comment: So please follow my answer ,as how does the lambda knows which account to connect? 
For your reference- 
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/

Answer (score 0):

You have:

- Amazon S3 bucket in `Account-A`
- Amazon Athena in `Account-A`
- AWS Lambda function in `Account-B`

(This differs from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60462501/174777), where you had Athena in `Account-B` accessing S3 in `Account-A`. In that scenario, a Bucket policy in `Account-A` was sufficient to grant access to S3 for Athena running in `Account-B`.)

Amazon Athena runs with the permissions of the IAM User or IAM Role that calls it. Therefore, the user or role that uses Athena needs permission to access the data in Amazon S3. In your previous question, this was accomplished via a Bucket Policy that provided Lambda with permission to access a bucket in a different account.

However, in *this* question, you have **Lambda in one account wanting to use Amazon Athena in a different account**. There is no ability to grant Athena access to users in a different account. Therefore, **your Lambda function will need to assume a role in the Athena account**.

Therefore:

- Create an IAM Role in `Account-A` (with Athena) that grants access to use Athena *and* the relevant Amazon S3 buckets
- The Lambda function in `Account-B`:

  - Should call `AssumeRole()` to 'become' the above role
  - Should use the credentials provided back to create a new `Session`, which is used to create a boto3 client for Athena

This will result in Lambda having access to Athena in `Account-A`, including any tables and views already created.

If you do not require the existing tables and views defined in Athena, then you could use Athena in the *same* account as Lambda, but the source S3 bucket would need to grant access to Lambda's IAM Role, as per your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60462501/174777).

Comment: Got this error An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::AccountB:assumed-role/Lambdar-Role/ETL-Lambda is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::AccountA:role/CrossAccount-Role

Comment: Create Execution Role (Lambdar-Role) for Lambda (ETL-Lambda) in Account B and modified code in lambda to below: sts_connection = boto3.client('sts')
    acct_b = sts_connection.assume_role(
        RoleArn="arn:aws:iam::AccountA:role/CrossAccount-Role",
        RoleSessionName="cross_acct_lambda"
    )

Comment: Got it worked! but when I put my Lambda withing VPC then Lambda is getting timed out. I also created STS and Athena vpc endpoint as well but still error.

Comment: Why are you putting the Lambda function in a VPC? If it is _not_ connected to a VPC, then it has Internet access and can make API calls. If it _is_ in a VPC, then it should be connected to a private subnet and there should be a NAT Gateway in a public subnet (with the private subnet Route Tables configured to use it).

Comment: As per compamy policy we need to keep all our Lambda's in private subnet of VPC. I resolved it by providing endpoint url as well like this: sts_connection = boto3.client('sts', region_name='us-west-2', endpoint_url='https://sts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'). Dont know ehy we need to provide endpoint url here. but this worked. Also, created VPC endpoint for STS.